# Printing Abbreviated Names in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write code in Java that will output abbreviated names based on input. For example; if the input is "John Alex Smith", the output is "Smith, J.A." And if the input is "John Smith", the output is "Smith, J." my code works perfectly fine if a first, middle, and last name are input, but it doesn't work if only a first and last are input, and I can't figure out why?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      String firstName = scnr.next();
      String middleName = scnr.next();
      String lastName = scnr.next();
      char middleInitial = middleName.charAt(0);
      char firstInitial = firstName.charAt(0);
      
      if (middleName.length() > 0 && lastName.length() == 0)   {
         lastName = middleName;
         System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstInitial + ".");   }
     
      else if (lastName.length() > 0) {
         System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstInitial + "." + middleInitial + ".");  }

      
      /* Type your code here. */
   }
}
```

Comment: What if name was `"José Eduardo Santos Tavares Melo Silva"`? Should result be `"Silva, J.E.S.T.M."`? Would seem so, but you'd have to rethink how you're approaching this, to handle unlimited number of parts to the name.

Comment: you should explain what it means when you say doesnt work .

Comment: The input is restricted to three names max. It gives me this error ` Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
 at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:9) `

Answer (score 0):

I assume your inputting 2 strings and then just pressing return for the case of a first and last name only? In which case `firstName` will have the first String. `middleName` will have the second String and then `lastName` will be an empty String . There are no conditions in your if else that support that siutation so nothing is printed.

You'll want to change it to check:

- If `firstName` or `middleName` is null or empty then that's an error
- Otherwise is last name not null and not empty? If so then that's 3 named input
- Otherwise it's 2 named input